# Is there a safe way for a web extension to have ui inside tab?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, content-script

browser web extension can provide ui to interact with the user such as (*sidebars* `sidebar_action`), or little icons that allow a popup upon click `browser_action`).

I however would like my extension to provide a user interface being displayed directly overlaying the the web page and hence in the center of the currently open tab. Right inside the tab. In order to display anything inside the tab I have though of using a [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world) and modify the web pages `DOM`, but it seems to me that this is not a safe method, as it would open up a possibilty for the untrusted web page's code to impact the UI (e.g. it could just delete the UI created, or worse modify it, hence interact maliciously in the communication between my `content-script`(the `web extension`) and the user.

The chromium documentation about [content-scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world) warns hence:

> **Stay secure**
>   While isolated worlds provide a layer of protection, using content
>   scripts can create vulnerabilities in an extension and the web page.

This question seesk for an answer if,

a) it is impossible to have a UI in the content area of a web page, that cannot also impacted by the web pages javascript (i.e. the DOM being always modifyable for both the content-script and the web page's javascript) or

b) there is a way to present a UI inside the content area of a web page, while in a "safe way" (meaning the web pages untrusted javascript, cannot impact the UI displayed).

Comment: Add an iframe element into the page with src pointing to an html file within your extension declared via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). That page will be an isolated extension page with full permissions (like the background page or browserAction popup). You can find detailed existing answers and even tutorials for this approach.

Comment: @wOxxOm iframe also occured to me briefly as a solution, however how would I make sure that (the iframe is actually visible and not covered underneath other `DOM` elements). Would the untrusted webpage's javascript not be able to remove the `iframe` from the DOM entirely (and then remake the a fake version of the UI)?

Comment: Having not trusted way to display (such as an overlay DOM) for web extensions seems to be quite a problem. Since `chromium` even decided to not provide `sidebar-action`, but instead motivate you to insert into the webpages `DOM` right away, this security issue is quite discouraging.

Comment: You'll have to check it manually e.g. by using MutationObserver and IntersectionObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm. your comments seem to picture the way to an feasible solution/answer. I will definitively try it out. With the Observers it seems abuse/attack from the web pages javascript can be reduced sufficiently, while the iframe already disabled much access in the first place. great!